# The problem with building the linux 6.7.1 kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm starting to build the make -j4 kernel. Then it gives you this error:

```
  LD [M]  net/mac802154/mac802154.ko
  LD [M]  net/dns_resolver/dns_resolver.ko
  LD [M]  net/ceph/libceph.ko
  LD [M]  net/batman-adv/batman-adv.ko
  LD [M]  net/nfc/nfc.ko
  LD [M]  net/nfc/nci/nci.ko
  LD [M]  net/nfc/nci/nci_spi.ko
  LD [M]  net/nfc/hci/hci.ko
  LD [M]  net/nfc/nfc_digital.ko
  LD [M]  net/psample/psample.ko
  LD [M]  net/ife/ife.ko
  LD [M]  net/openvswitch/openvswitch.ko
  LD [M]  net/openvswitch/vport-vxlan.ko
  LD [M]  net/openvswitch/vport-geneve.ko
  LD [M]  net/openvswitch/vport-gre.ko
  LD [M]  net/vmw_vsock/vsock.ko
  LD [M]  net/vmw_vsock/vsock_diag.ko
  LD [M]  net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_vmci_transport.ko
  LD [M]  net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_virtio_transport.ko
  LD [M]  net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common.ko
  LD [M]  net/vmw_vsock/vsock_loopback.ko
  LD [M]  net/nsh/nsh.ko
  LD [M]  net/hsr/hsr.ko
  LD [M]  net/qrtr/qrtr.ko
  LD [M]  net/qrtr/qrtr-mhi.ko
  LD [M]  virt/lib/irqbypass.ko
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
```

What could be the problem? Please help me!

Here is my build config: [enter here](https://cloud.belykh.io/s/CBigawYfdmD7Jfy)

Comment: you're not actually showing the part of the log that shows what went wrong, I'd assume; often you get the output from the tasks that are still running in parallel after some compilation unit failed to compile. So, the actual error is probably somewhere slightly further "up". Can you paste the full build log output somewhere?

Comment: @GAD3R [link](https://cloud.belykh.io/s/yFniL96d3zNiSHN) Here is the makefile

Comment: vote to close as lacking as unclear due to lacking necessary logs

Comment: also, a Makefile where you hand-modified Variables will not work for reproduction, especially when these modifications entail things like quotes in the middle of strings.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I didn't change anything in the Makefile, I changed the generated .config and that's it.

Comment: Surprised your `NAME = Hurr durr I'ma ninja sloth` did not upset `make`, then! Anyways, full build log, please.

Comment: that is less helpful than the full build log, and I've been asking for that thrice now.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What event logs do you need? Please write, don't I understand you?

Comment: you're missing the lines your `make` run output before the lines you pasted. That's what I've been asking you for.

Comment: Good grief, just run `make` on its own & post the last few lines. I am guessing it's to do with the certificates again.